Selenium + Dash: Waiting for a dcc.Dropdown value = Apple not found, found: Apple
I'm trying to set a value to a dcc.Dropdown with dash_duo but I already fail at the previous step, obtaining its value:
import dash
from dash import dcc


def test_001_dropdown(dash_duo):

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    app.layout = dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Banana', 'value': 'Banana'},
            {'label': 'Apple', 'value': 'Apple'},
            {'label': 'Orange', 'value': 'Orange'}],
        value='Apple')

    dash_duo.start_server(app)

    dash_duo.wait_for_text_to_equal('#my-dropdown', 'Apple', timeout=1)

It fails quite dubious:

FAILED dropdown_test.py::test_001_dropdown -
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: text -> Apple
not found within 1s, found: Apple

I'm even puzzled, that it actually finds "Apple" (but not "Apple" somehow), cause Apple is not the text value of #my-dropdown but  #react-select-2--value-item a bit further down the div-tree. Is wait_for_text_to_equal capable of searching text entries of decedents recursively?
<div id="my-dropdown" class="dash-dropdown">
   <div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
      <div class="Select-control">
         <div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value">
            <div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-item">Apple</span></div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
               <input autocomplete="off" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;" value="">
               <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


Note this is a "TimeoutException : [...] Apple not found within 1s".

@EricLavault I does not mattero if I change it to 1 or 100 seconds. The fact, that the string "Apple" has been found but not found, doesn't change
